# Поиск определения кода php в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем доброго дня. Суть моей проблемы в том что мне не удается найти в тексте определитель языка php  точнее

```
$textone="<?php echo\"<a href='ch.php?mid=416&cid=21'>Вопросы</a>\";  ?>";
$texttwo="<html> <a href='ch.php?mid=416&cid=21'>Вопросы</a>  </html>";



if(preg_match("/\b<?php\b/i",$textone))
{
 echo"Найден фрагмент <?php";
}
else
{
 echo"Не найден фрагмент <?php";
}
```

Если я в функцию preg_match указываю обе переменные $textone и $texttwo то получаю результат TRUE  в обоих случаях. Мне нужно получить FALSE если в preg_match переменная $texttwo , но функция берет кусок из текста с содержанием в ссылках .php и выдает ее за true,  а мне нужно TRUE только с содержанием в тексте "

Comment: `<\?(?:php|=|\s)\s*` [В песочнице](https://regex101.com/r/tO0rhB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение не правильно, попробуйте такое `/<\?php|<\?=/i`

`<?=` это короткое значение `echo`